# Problem of TabBarController related to HIG guideline

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use tabBarController but its root view will not be the first view which the user will see on launching the application . When the user will launch the applicaion he will see the tabbar but no item selected in it i.e; the view he will see will not be the root view of the UITabbarController rather it will be some other view of some different viewcontroller.Now if the user select any of the tab bar item the corresponding view controller's view wil be shown to him.

To return to this home page i will give something like home button on each of the tab bar cntroller's view.On clicking home button the user will come back to this firt view containing tab bar with no item selected.

Is this acceptable according to HIG guidlines or the application will get rejected???? Because many of the blogs strictly discourage to do anything like this.According to them the tabbar controller's root view has to be the fist view shown in the application.

But I remember I have seen an application like this but do not remember its exact name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any application has ever been rejected because it didn't follow the HIG. If so, 90% of apps would never have been accepted.